# Math Challenge print the next largest number after shuffling using javascript

Tags: javascript, math

> Have the function nextLargest(num) take the num parameter being passed and return the next number greater than num using the same digits. For example: if num is 123 return 132, if it's 12453 return 12534. If a number has no greater permutations, return -1 (ie. 999).

> Examples
>
> ```
> Input: 11121
> Output: 11211
> Input: 41352
> Output: 41523
> ```

```
var permute = (function () {
    return permute;

    function permute(list) {
        return list.length ?
            list.reduce(permutate, []) :
            [[]];
    }
    
    function permutate(permutations, item, index, list) {
        return permutations.concat(permute(
            list.slice(0, index).concat(
            list.slice(index + 1)))
            .map(concat ,[item]));
    }
    
    function concat(list) {
        return this.concat(list);
    }

}());

console.log(JSON.stringify(permute([1,2,3,4])));
```

my output : `[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,4,3],[1,3,2,4],[1,3,4,2],[1,4,2,3],[1,4,3,2],[2,1,3,4],[2,1,4,3],[2,3,1,4],[2,3,4,1],[2,4,1,3],[2,4,3,1],[3,1,2,4],[3,1,4,2],[3,2,1,4],[3,2,4,1],[3,4,1,2],[3,4,2,1],[4,1,2,3],[4,1,3,2],[4,2,1,3],[4,2,3,1],[4,3,1,2],[4,3,2,1]]`

expected output :

```
Input: 11121
Output: 11211
Input: 41352
Output: 41523
```

Comment: Your code never logs `Input:` and `Output:`, why do you expect that?

Comment: Where is your `nextLargest` function?

Comment: You could sort all the permutations lexicographically. Then find the one immediately after the original array.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `permute` function as given that you shared in your question, the following straightforward approach should solve the question.

It is not very efficient, however. Probably, a better strategy could be found working with a cleverly chosen sequence of transpositions only.

```js
function nextLargest(input) {
  let x = input.toString();
  let p = permute([...x]);
  let result = Infinity;
  for (let n of p) {
    let y = n.join('')*1;
    if (y > input && y < result) result = y; 
  }
  return result < Infinity ? result : -1;
}
  
console.log(nextLargest(1234));  // <<< gives 1243
```